# Como passar um ponteiro dentro de uma struct por parâmetro de uma função?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

A situação é a seguinte:

Possuo uma struct com um campo que é um ponteiro de ponteiro, no entanto desejo passar como parâmetro em uma função somente o ponteiro apontado, isto é, o ponteiro mais interno desse meu campo na struct:

Em código seria assim:

```
typdef struct
{  
  int **ponteiro;
}Ponteiro;
```

Tenho a atribuição de endereçamento desta forma:

```
 grafo->vertices[posicao_B].vertice_adjacente[(grafo->vertices[posicao_B].qtd_adj‌​acentes-1)] = &grafo->vertices[posicao_A];  <-- aqui estou tentando fazer com que o ponteiro de ponteiro (**vertice_adjacente) aponte para o endereço  de  (&grafo->vertices[posicao_A])
```

E estou tentando imprimir assim, porém não está sendo impresso nada:

```
printf("Vertice adjacente de A %d\n",(grafo->vertices[posicao_A].vertice_adjacente[0]->num_vertice));
```

Só lembrando que (vertice_adjacente) é um array de ponteiros alocados dinamicamente por uma função que desenvolvi.

Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: Dê mais contexto de como está usando este código.

Comment: No caso, você está querendo passar `int **ponteiro`  como parametro ou o primeiro ponteiro de `int **ponteiro`, que seria `int *ponteiro`?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {int **ponteiro;} Ponteiro;

Ponteiro a;
int b;
int *c = &b;
a.ponteiro = &c;

fx(a.ponteiro);     // &c         : tipo int **
fx(*(a.ponteiro));  // &b         : tipo int *
fx(**(a.ponteiro)); // valor de b : tipo int
```

Comment: grafo->vertices[posicao_B].vertice_adjacente[(grafo->vertices[posicao_B].qtd_adjacentes-1)] = &grafo->vertices[posicao_A];

Comment: Desta forma:    tenho um Ponteiro de uma struct  grafo, onde internamente nela há um ponteiro de Vertices - esse ponteiro foi alocado como um vetor de vertices - e nela há um ponteiro de ponteiro do tipo Vertice- sendo este campo 'vertices_adjacente'.

Comment: Estou fazendo a atribuição de apontadores corretamente? Conforme código abaixo:  grafo->vertices[posicao_A].vertice_adjacente[(grafo->vertices[posicao_A].qtd_adjacentes)] = &grafo->vertices[posicao_B];                                                                                              E sua impressão:  printf("Vertice adjacente de A %d\n",(grafo->vertices[posicao_A].vertice_adjacente[0]->num_vertice));     Estou fazendo corretamente?  Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Altera a tua pergunta com estas novas informações. Aqui num comentário não é fácil perceber o código correctamente.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, acho que agora dá de entender.